# HTML functions don't return value when click on button

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote the code provided. But on clicking the button, nothing appears.

```js
function calculate() {
  var colony = document.getElementById("co").value;
  var dilution = document.getElementById("dil").value;
  var inoculum = document.getElementById("in").value;
  var b = parseFloat(dilution) * parseFloat(inoculum);
  var c = parseFloat(colony) / b;
  if (!isNaN(c)) {
    document.getElementById("multiplication").innerHTML = "the conentration is " + c;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="calculate">Calculate</button>
<p id="multiplication"></p>
```

Comment: Hello! Please read [Question Check](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) list and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Can you please update the question with complete html you have wrote, the current code doesn't have ids co, dil, in

Comment: again... http://stevesouders.com/hpws/rule-js-bottom.php

Answer (score 1):

1. You didn't call `calculate()` function. It should be `onclick="calculate()"` not `onclick="calculate"`.
2. There's no `value` property in an element. Use `innerText` property of an element.

```js
function calculate() {
  var colony = document.getElementById("co").innerText;
  var dilution = document.getElementById("dil").innerText;
  var inoculum = document.getElementById("in").innerText;
  var b = parseFloat(dilution) * parseFloat(inoculum);
  var c = parseFloat(colony) / b;
  if (!isNaN(c)) {
    document.getElementById("multiplication").innerHTML = "the conentration is " + c;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
<p id="multiplication"></p>
<div id="co">1</div>
<div id="dil">2</div>
<div id="in">4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the HTML, which wasn't provided in the shared code
and it works. It is permissible for input fields to not have an ID attribute.

**Client Side:**

```
function calculate() {
    var colony = document.getElementById("co").value;
    var dilution = document.getElementById("dil").value;
    var inoculum = document.getElementById("in").value;
    var b = parseFloat(dilution) * parseFloat(inoculum);
    var c = parseFloat(colony) / b;
    if (!isNaN(c)) {
        document.getElementById("multiplication").innerHTML =
            "the conentration is " + c;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
    co: <input type="text" id="co"><br>
    dil: <input type="text" id="dil"><br>
    in: <input type="text" id="in"><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
    <div id="multiplication">fff</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your inital code, your `onclick="calculate"` was missing `()` after calculate.
I've added that as well as a `script` tag within your html with your JavaScript function without changing much of your original code's text.

Working Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yuL58da1/

For presentation/educational purposes, I solved the problem using JQuery as well to show you what the solution would look like using JQuery.

Working JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4g9ayoqb/

Using the JQuery method, I've updated your html `button` to include a `id` attribute and removed `onclick`:

`<button id="calculate" type="button">Calculate</button>`

and added a JQuery click selector for that button's id:

`$(document).on('click','#calculate',function()`

Comment: The question contains no jQuery nor the jQuery tag

Comment: I've updated my answer showing both the Javascript way and the Jquery way to solve the problem. Just to show an example that JQuery could be used as well for educational purposes.